# how do you run multiple java files at the same time?

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am using jGrasp ide for java and am trying to create a Client/Server program. The Server is in one class and the Client is another program entirely. However, when I try to run the Client Class, while the Server class is already running I get a dialog box that says Run Active, OK to end Run? What I need to do is be able to have my Server class running and then run the client class without shutting down the server class.

Answer (score 0):

You won't access a class within your client from the server. As you said yourself, your client is a different program entirely.

What you want is for your server and client(s) programs to ***communicate*** with each-other when both are running (independently) at the same time.

I suggest following this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SocketProgramming/SocketProgram.html

Comment: so is it possible to compile and run to files at once in jGrasp or not?

Comment: @TylerGrim (Sigh...) No, not in the sense you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, jGRASP can only run one user program at a time.

If you turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages", you will see "Actual Command Sent" in the output. You can copy that and paste into a command prompt window to execute the command from outside jGRASP (cd to the correct working directory first).